# How can i allow /(slash) on ASP.NET Core Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to using ASP.NET
I'd like to put slashes in url for various addresses on MVC Controller.
This is url that I'm thinking of:

- localhost/file/a/d/aaa.zip?key=randomkeystring
  first `a` is drive name, `d` is folder's name, `aaa.zip` is file name, `key` query is own key to allow requests.

Just wanted to know how can I allow / on Controllers.
Here is some codes I made it (I think this is not related or so)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("file/")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FileController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string uri)
        {
            //if (!Directory.Exists(uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("/"))))
            //return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead("");
            return Ok(uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("/")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very unsecure to give user possibility to read from any drive/directory.

Comment: You should URL encode the value when passing as parameter to controller and then URL decode the value in the code before using it. Example `D:\MyFoldere\SubFolder\fmile.txt` value is URL encoded to `D%3A%5CMyFoldere%5CSubFolder%5Cfmile.txt`

Comment: @leszek-mazur this is my some hobby project that requires key o.o
It will be need own key and there will be directory permissions to not accessible of users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[Route("file")]` over controller.

Add `[HttpGet("{driveName}/{folderName}/{fileName}")]` above `action`. Also update action parameters as `GetFile(string driveName, string folderName, string fileName)`.

It indicates that for `localhost/file/a/d/aaa.zip?key=randomkeystring` after `file/` it will map `a` to `driveName` route parameter, `d` to `folderName` route parameter and so on.

Check this for more details about `Route` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

```
namespace Server.Controllers
{
    [Route("file")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FileController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{driveName}/{folderName}/{fileName}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetFile(string driveName, string folderName, string fileName)
        {
            //if (!Directory.Exists(uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("/"))))
            //return File(System.IO.File.OpenRead("");
            return Ok(uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("/")));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering the questions!
But i need to get parent's folder like `https://localhost:5001/file/a/b/c.zip` or `https://localhost:5001/file/a/b/c/e/f.zip` is it possible?

Comment: Ok i did `[HttpGet("{driveName}/{**name}")]` and it works, thanks for giving the URL to help me!